# Add up to 5 select fields based on a mysql created select form

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, forms

I have a pretty complex form with user data entered into a MySQL database. A user's role can be either Manager or Assistant. I want to create a link between a manager and assistant. A manager can have more than 1 assistants. An assistant can work for more than 1 manager.

I got as far that I can reveal a select line based upon the role. So if a role is manager, a select line is created from all the users with assistant as role in the MySQL database and vise versa.

This works fine, but how can I create a new field for up to 5 Assistants (or managers) by clicking a button and in such a way that it again generates a select line from the database, AND minus the user(s) that were already selected?

For the revealing of the correct field I am using this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$('#role').on('change', function() {
  var selection = $(this).val();
  switch (selection) {
    case "Manager":
      $("#assistant").show()
      $('#manager').hide()
      break;
    case "Assistant":
      $("#manager").show()
      $("#assistant").hide()
      break;
    default:
      $("#manager").hide()
      $('#assistant').hide()
  }
});

});//]]>
```

The select field is created like this:

```
<td><select name="linkmgr[]" id="manager" style="display:none;"><option selected="selected"></option>
<?php $connmgr = new mysqli('localhost', 'admin', 'password', 'db') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');

    $resultmgr = $connmgr->query("SELECT id, full_name FROM userdata WHERE role='Manager' ORDER BY full_name");
        while ($rowmgr = $resultmgr->fetch_assoc()) {

                  unset($idmgr, $fullname_mgr);
                  $idmgr = $rowmgr['id'];
                  $fullname_mgr = $rowmgr['full_name']; 
                 echo '<option value="'.$idmgr.'">'.$fullname_mgr.'</option>';

}
?></select></td>
```

At this moment, the form nicely enters the user-ID of the Assistant (or manager) into the database. I want to comma separate the data into the database when more than 1 assistant (or manager) is selected. This I have figured out already.

Both fields are created similarly. 
I hope I explained well enough what I would like to accomplish and that I showed my crappy programming sufficiently to guide me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: _“I want to comma separate the data into the database when more than 1 assistant (or manager) is selected. This I have figured out already.”_ - only that that’s rather _wrong_ already ... you should properly _normalize_ this, otherwise you will very likely run into other issues related to that sub-optimal decision later on.

Comment: Plus, you could have this _much_ easier, if you just used one select field that allows for _multiple_ selections. A limitation to max. 5 selections you would have to implement yourself using JS (plus server-side validation, of course) ... but you would not have the trouble of checking which users where selected already to exclude those in the next select field to generate.

Answer (score 0):

basicly, what you are looking at, is many - to - many database relation.
More of a propper aproach would requare 3 tables (one for managers, one for assistants and one to manage their relations (table of unique pairs of managers and assistants working togethor)), and propper foreign keys set. Cant give you more detail, but i hope this will leed you on the right track:)

Comment: The answer I put was for you... thanks again.

I may have found a solution or workaround by using the multiple tag in the Select form. Then I immediately have the choice to select one OR more.

Comment: Now that i read the question once again, i think i kind of missed it almost completely:D But i'm happy you found your way and moving forward! :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reaction, but in principle I have this covered. It's already working the way I want it, except to add the extra lines when needed. The injection into the database with comma separated values I have used before and it works OK. It will be taken care of by:

```
if (empty($_POST['linkmgr'])){
        $linkmgr=($_POST['linkmgr']);
        } else { 
            foreach($_POST['linkmgr'] as $mgr){
            $varmgr[]=$mgr;
            $linkmgr=implode(", ",$varmgr);
            }
        }`
```